# Tag filter still emails me after I have deleted it

Tags: bug, email, tag-filters, subscription

I was messing around with filters last night and set one up for JavaScript with email notifications, every 15 minutes -- silly thing to do, I know.

I woke up this morning to many emails unsurprisingly informing me of the hundreds of JavaScript questions that had been posted while I was sleeping. Obviously I don't want an e-mail every 15 minutes for one of the most popular tags on StackOverflow.

So I went to the filters page and hit 'delete this filter'. The filter disappeared, but the emails are still coming through!

I've tried navigating to the specific filter by clicking the link in the filter confirmation email, but I can't edit it anymore.

Are they supposed to still send? How can I stop them?

Comment: How long did you wait after unsubscribing? \*cough\*caching\*cough\*

Comment: It's been around 8 or 9 hours and still receiving them. Should I have waited longer before complaining?

Comment: That seems like a reasonable enough wait to me. An hour sounds like caching. 9 hours sounds like a bug

Comment: You're still getting emails for the deleted subscriptions?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure am. I've sent an email to the SE team too. Having to run a rule that moves the emails straight into the bin when they come in.

Comment: So the bug is probably awfully silly: when subscription is *deleted*, it's not being *unsubscribed* first.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure; that's pretty much the gist.